# Wrong Label Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I'm trying to get the height of the label based on the length of the text. But if the word can not fit in one line - part of the word is transferred to the next line. And the method returns the height of only one row. Can anyone help me ?

```
- (CGFloat)heightFromText:(NSString *)text{
if (!text) {
    return 0.0;
}
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithColorCode:@"438fbe"];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color, NSFontAttributeName : font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};
NSAttributedString *attributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
CGRect needed = [attributed boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:nil];
CGFloat textHeight = ceilf(needed.size.height);
return textHeight;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try a UILabel instead, something like this:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
lbl.font=font; 
lbl.numberOfLines=0; // will do as many lines as you need
lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
lbl.attributedText=attString;

CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(lbl.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
return size.height;
```

Comment: And so what height specified when I create the label? 0.0 ?

Comment: doesn't matter - 0 should be okay

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR_FONT" size:FONT_SIZE], NSFontAttributeName, nil];

CGRect frame = [YOUR_TEXT boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAX_FRAME_WIDTH, MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];

CGSize size = frame.size;
```